# Javascript Balloon generator/manipulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, canvas

Is there any javascript(/jquery) framework/plugin which generates Balloons? The one that can be used in Comics. The balloon dynamically expands and contracts based on the length of the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one [here](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?page=tooltip), demo [here](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/bubble-tooltip/bubble-tooltip.html). (I was just curious — your question made me go "Hey, that would be cool" — and did a search; no idea whether it's any good.)